# R non-finite function value

Tags: математика, r, rstudio

```
integrand<-function(x){
e^(2*x)/sqrt(e^(4*x)-3)
}
integrate(integrand,-Inf, Inf)
```

После попытки интегрирования выдает ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экспонента в R задается при помощи функции `exp()`.

В Вашем выражении все равно есть проблема с математикой, но вот это выражение у меня работает:

```
integrand<-function(x){
  exp(2*x)/sqrt(exp(4*x)-3)
}
integrate(integrand, 1, 100)

# 99.00701 with absolute error < 0.0034
```